# Most generic way to compute the middle value

Tags: c++, generic-programming

I have two values of some generic numeric type. The only known thing is that one is less than the other. I do not know if they are signed or unsigned, if they are integral or floating point. I need to compute the value which is in the middle between the two, so half of their distance. For example, given the range [1,11] the result would be 6:

```
unsigned middle(const unsigned min,const unsigned max)
{
    return (max + min) / 2U;
}
```

But the example is of course not generic enough for all the cases and for all the types.
What can I replace this with?

Comment: should the return type be same type as the input? There is no one right choice, sometimes you want average of integers as integer sometimes as floating point value

Comment: Regarding "all the types", begin by learning about *templates*.

Comment: Another approach would be to overload the method for all the cases you need to treat (double, float, int, unsigned int, long). This way, you cannot call middle with.. char, for example.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the two arguments min and max for each given computation have the same type?

Comment: Do you have issue with `template <typename T> T middle(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) { return (lhs + rhs) / 2; }`?

Comment: @Jarod42 yes I have: the sum can very easily overflow once the values are high enough

Comment: Are you looking for [std::midpoint](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/dh7pxr/cppcon_2019_marshall_clow_stdmidpoint_how_hard/)?. This is far from trivial.

Comment: @Jabberwocky yes! Is there a boost version or std experimental of it? I need to be using C++17

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 I don't think so, but look at the link I provided, watch the video etc. and maybe you could implement it yourself for c++17.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is fundamentally different for integer types and floating-point types. I'll assume that fixed-point types, `std::complex` and other less-common numerical types are not necessary.

For N-bit integer types, the difference can be anything between -1<>N, which is an N+1 bit range. That's solved when you realize that the midpoint of (-5, 2) is the same as the midpoint of (2, -5). Hence, for integer types you can just defer to `T middle_impl(std::min<T>, std::max<T>)`. In the implementation, you'll need `std::make_unsigned<T>::type` to hold the difference.

For floating-point the problem is mostly with denormal values. Usually, `a/2` just decrements the exponent by one, and that's an exact operation (no rounding). Hence `a+b/2==a/2+b/2`. But `a+b` may be denormal even if `a` and `b` themselves aren't. You also get the additional problem of `middle(-std::numeric_limits<FP>::infinity(), +std::numeric_limits<FP>::infinity())` which has to be `NaN` not zero. All NaN inputs of course need to give a NaN output, but that is rarely a problem. Just don't forget it in your test cases.